# Why is Intellij Idea Java IDE not recognizing updates to my local maven projects

Tags: java, maven, ide, intellij-idea

I created an Intellij-idea (11.1) single module project based on a maven projects, some of the maven dependencies are other projects also created by me.

All these other projects  have been installed locally with `mvn install` and everything was working okay.

However the problem occurs when I make a change to one of these local projects such as adding a new method, despite running `mvn install`  and resychronizing main project pom I cannot get IntelliJ to be aware of the new methods I've added. If I build my main project with mvn it works okay its only within Intellij itself that I have a problem.

Comment: Are you importing your project as Maven project? (*Import from external model*)?

Comment: Yes I am, it works okay to start with

Answer (score 5):

I can assume that you do not use SNAPSHOT in version e.g.

```
  <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

if you use just

```
version>1.0</version>
```

It means that version 1.0 is stable and any project that has dependency on it will download it just once (at first time).

```
SNAPSHOT - shows that current project is under development so your maven will download it each time you run install
```

More information you can find in [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

Comment: Thanks I think you must be right, I assumed SNAPSHOT was just a naming convention, although it does seem to pick up changes sometimes.

Comment: Will maven and/or IDEA really treat dependencies with SNAPSHOT differently? Is there any official information on this?

Comment: Actually I don't think this is the issue, the same project on another machine picks up changes to maven project. Im just going to recreate the Intellij project base don the maven code.